# Tabhost - restore container view after tabHost.getTabWidget().removeView()

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tabhost

Application has dynamic adding\removing of tabs. And the `TabHost` seems to be tricky with removing.

The problem is to restore view of tab after it was removed. Correct me if I'm wrong but `mTabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(removeId))` removes container View together with tab.

After a sequece of actions: **add tab - add content - remove tab - add tab - add content** the content isn't displayed anymore although the instance of container fragment is created. Debugging shows that `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` are never called again after tab delete.

**Anyone faced such problem?**

---

**CODE:**

Remove tab:

```
mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
mTabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(removeId));
```

Create tab:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tag, null),
                    GridFragment.class, args);
```

And I have a custom `TabHost` class based on original which shows\hides tabs on their switch instead of deleting:

```
package com.itinnovations.bitrekmonitor.view.navigation_activity.fragments.tabs_fragment.utility;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabWidget;

public class CustomTabHost extends TabHost
    implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
private FrameLayout mRealTabContent;
private Context mContext;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private int mContainerId;
private TabHost.OnTabChangeListener mOnTabChangeListener;
private TabInfo mLastTab;
private boolean mAttached;

static final class TabInfo {
    private final String tag;
    private final Class<?> clss;
    private final Bundle args;
    private Fragment fragment;

    TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
        tag = _tag;
        clss = _class;
        args = _args;
    }
}

static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
    private final Context mContext;

    public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }
}

static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
    String curTab;

    SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
        super(superState);
    }

    private SavedState(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        curTab = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        out.writeString(curTab);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FragmentTabHost.SavedState{"
                + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))
                + " curTab=" + curTab + "}";
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
        public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SavedState(in);
        }

        public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SavedState[size];
        }
    };
}

public CustomTabHost(Context context) {
    // Note that we call through to the version that takes an AttributeSet,
    // because the simple Context construct can result in a broken object!
    super(context, null);
    initFragmentTabHost(context, null);
}

public CustomTabHost(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initFragmentTabHost(context, attrs);
}

private void initFragmentTabHost(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            new int[] { android.R.attr.inflatedId }, 0, 0);
    mContainerId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
    a.recycle();

    super.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    // If owner hasn't made its own view hierarchy, then as a convenience
    // we will construct a standard one here.
    if (findViewById(android.R.id.tabs) == null) {
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        addView(ll, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        TabWidget tw = new TabWidget(context);
        tw.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
        tw.setOrientation(TabWidget.HORIZONTAL);
        ll.addView(tw, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));

        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(context);
        fl.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        ll.addView(fl, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0, 0));

        mRealTabContent = fl = new FrameLayout(context);
        mRealTabContent.setId(mContainerId);
        ll.addView(fl, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 1));
    }
}

/**
 * @deprecated Don't call the original TabHost setup, you must instead
 * call {@link #setup(Context, FragmentManager)} or
 * {@link #setup(Context, FragmentManager, int)}.
 */
@Override @Deprecated
public void setup() {
    throw new IllegalStateException(
            "Must call setup() that takes a Context and FragmentManager");
}

public void setup(Context context, FragmentManager manager) {
    super.setup();
    mContext = context;
    mFragmentManager = manager;
    ensureContent();
}

public void setup(Context context, FragmentManager manager, int containerId) {
    super.setup();
    mContext = context;
    mFragmentManager = manager;
    mContainerId = containerId;
    ensureContent();
    mRealTabContent.setId(containerId);

    // We must have an ID to be able to save/restore our state.  If
    // the owner hasn't set one at this point, we will set it ourself.
    if (getId() == View.NO_ID) {
        setId(android.R.id.tabhost);
    }
}

private void ensureContent() {
    if (mRealTabContent == null) {
        mRealTabContent = (FrameLayout)findViewById(mContainerId);
        if (mRealTabContent == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "No tab content FrameLayout found for id " + mContainerId);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void setOnTabChangedListener(OnTabChangeListener l) {
    mOnTabChangeListener = l;
}

public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
    tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
    String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

    TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);

    if (mAttached) {
        // If we are already attached to the window, then check to make
        // sure this tab's fragment is inactive if it exists.  This shouldn't
        // normally happen.
        info.fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (info.fragment != null && !info.fragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(info.fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    mTabs.add(info);
    addTab(tabSpec);
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    String currentTab = getCurrentTabTag();

    // Go through all tabs and make sure their fragments match
    // the correct state.
    FragmentTransaction ft = null;
    for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
        TabInfo tab = mTabs.get(i);
        tab.fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tab.tag);
        if (tab.fragment != null && !tab.fragment.isDetached()) {
            if (tab.tag.equals(currentTab)) {
                // The fragment for this tab is already there and
                // active, and it is what we really want to have
                // as the current tab.  Nothing to do.
                mLastTab = tab;
            } else {
                // This fragment was restored in the active state,
                // but is not the current tab.  Deactivate it.
                if (ft == null) {
                    ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                }
                ft.detach(tab.fragment);
            }
        }
    }

    // We are now ready to go.  Make sure we are switched to the
    // correct tab.
    mAttached = true;
    ft = doTabChanged(currentTab, ft);
    if (ft != null) {
        ft.commit();
        mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    mAttached = false;
}

@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
    ss.curTab = getCurrentTabTag();
    return ss;
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    SavedState ss = (SavedState)state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
    setCurrentTabByTag(ss.curTab);
}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    if (mAttached) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = doTabChanged(tabId, null);
        if (ft != null) {
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
    if (mOnTabChangeListener != null) {
        mOnTabChangeListener.onTabChanged(tabId);
    }
}

private FragmentTransaction doTabChanged(String tabId, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    TabInfo newTab = null;
    for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
        TabInfo tab = mTabs.get(i);
        if (tab.tag.equals(tabId)) {
            newTab = tab;
        }
    }
    if (newTab == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No tab known for tag " + tabId);
    }
    if (mLastTab != newTab) {
        if (ft == null) {
            ft = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        }
        if (mLastTab != null) {
            if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                ft.hide(mLastTab.fragment); //this was changed
            }
        }
        if (newTab != null) {
            if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mContext,
                        newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                ft.add(mContainerId, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);
                findViewById(mContainerId).setContentDescription("DEBUG. add fragment to this container");
            } else {
                if (newTab.fragment.isHidden()){
                    ft.show(newTab.fragment); //this was changed
                }
                else{
                    ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
                }
            }
        }

        mLastTab = newTab;
    }
    return ft;
}
```

}

*P.S. I know that `ViewPager` is much easier with deleting but it doesn't suit requirements. Also `removeAllViews()` and recreating them manually doesn't really helps since there's problem with saving\restoring state of removed fragments*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `TabLayout` instead of `TabHost`. It is more flexible and works fine with tab deletion.

Init:

```
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mAdapter = new NewTabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity(), mTabsContent);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Delete from tab host activity\fragment:

```
public void removeTab(int position) {
    if (mTabLayout.getTabCount() >= 1 && position < mTabLayout.getTabCount()) {
        mTabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
        mAdapter.removeTabPage(position);
    }
}
```

`removeTabPage(position)` in Adapter:

```
public void removeTabPage(int position) {
    if (!mTabs.isEmpty() && position < mTabs.size()) {
        mTabs.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```